# How to solve $h(i) = \frac{i^2}{(n-i)^2+i^2}h(i-1) + \frac{(n-i)^2}{(n-i)^2+i^2}h(i+1)$

Tags: markov-chains, problem-solving

$h(i) = $P(reach n eventually| the initial state = i)

$h(0) = 0$

$h(n) = 1$

0 and n are stopping time.

For $ 0 < i < n$,

$$h(i) = \frac{i^2}{(n-i)^2+i^2}h(i-1) + \frac{(n-i)^2}{(n-i)^2+i^2}h(i+1)$$

How to solve for $h(i)$?

Comment: unclear question. Are you looking for explicit formation of $h(i)$ ?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for something in terms of i and n.

Comment: Because this is the final part of my solution, so I forgot to mention a lot of details... Anyway, I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to write $h(i+1)-h(i)$ in terms of $h(i)-h(i-1)$
I think you get $${n-1\choose i}^2(h(i+1)-h(i))=h(1)-h(0)$$

Comment: I tried before, and I got $h(i) = h(0) + \sum(\frac{i}{n-i})^{2(j-1)}[h(1)-h(0)]$

I know $h(0)$, but what is $h(1)$?

Comment: That is nearly correct.  You don't get $(i/(n-i))^{2(j-1)}$ because the $i$ changes at each step.  You get a sum of a product, which needs factorials.  To find $h(1)$, use $h(n)=1$

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that $h(i) = k^i$ for an arbitrary k. So the problem changes to

$$k^i = \dfrac{i^2}{(n-i)^2 +i^2}k^{i-1}+\dfrac{(n-i)^2}{(n-i)^2+i^2}k^{i+1}$$

assuming that $k \neq 0$ we have

$$\dfrac{(n-i)^2}{(n-i)^2+i^2}k^{2}-k+\dfrac{i^2}{(n-i)^2 +i^2}= 0$$

so

$$k= \dfrac{1 \pm \sqrt{1-4\dfrac{(n-i)^2i^2}{((n-i)^2+i^2)^2}}}{\dfrac{2(n-i)^2}{(n-i)^2+i^2}}$$

Now assume that the solution is a lineal combination from the previous answers ($k_1$ and $k_2$) so

$$h(i) = m_1k_1^i + m_2k^i_2$$

replace on your original equation , solve the $m_i$ terms and conclude.

---

Edit: I just noticed that $k$ may be reduced:

$$k= \dfrac{1 \pm \sqrt{1-4\dfrac{(n-i)^2i^2}{((n-i)^2+i^2)^2}}}{\dfrac{2(n-i)^2}{(n-i)^2+i^2}} =\dfrac{((n-i)^2+i^2)\pm((n-i)^2-i^2)}{2(n-i)^2}$$

so

$$k_1 =\dfrac{2(n-i)^2}{2(n-i)^2}= 1 \land k_2 = \dfrac{i^2}{(n-i)^2}$$

Comment: The problem is that there is no reason to guarantee the assumption $h(i) = k^i$

Answer (score 0):

It is a matrix equation:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\frac{1^2}{(n-1)^2+1^2} & 0 & \frac{(n-1)^2}{(n-1)^2+1^2} & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & \frac{2^2}{(n-2)^2+2^2} & 0 & \frac{(n-2)^2}{(n-2)^2+2^2} & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & \frac{3^2}{(n-3)^2+3^2} & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0& 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{4^2}{(n-4)^2+4^2} & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ...&   \frac{3^2}{3^2+(n-3)^2} & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ...&  0 & \frac{2^2}{2^2+(n-2)^2} & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ...& \frac{(n-1)^2}{1^2+(n-1)^2} & 0 & \frac{1^2}{1^2+(n-1)^2} \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\times
\begin{bmatrix}
h_0=0 \\ 
h_1 \\ 
h_2 \\ 
h_3 \\ 
h_4 \\ 
\vdots \\ 
h_{n-3} \\
h_{n-2} \\ 
h_{n-1} \\ 
h_n=1 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 
h_1 \\ 
h_2 \\ 
h_3 \\ 
h_4 \\ 
\vdots \\ 
h_{n-3} \\
h_{n-2} \\ 
h_{n-1} \\ 
h_n=1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Removing $h_0$ and $h_n$ and bringing all other $h_i$ to left hand side:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & \frac{(n-1)^2}{(n-1)^2+1^2} & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ 
\frac{2^2}{(n-2)^2+2^2} & -1 & \frac{(n-2)^2}{(n-2)^2+2^2} & \cdots & 0 & \\ 
0 & \frac{3^2}{(n-3)^2+3^2} & -1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & \frac{4^2}{(n-4)^2+4^2} & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & ...&   \frac{3^2}{3^2+(n-3)^2} & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & ...&  -1 & \frac{2^2}{2^2+(n-2)^2} \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & ...& \frac{(n-1)^2}{1^2+(n-1)^2} & -1 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
\times
\begin{bmatrix}
h_1 \\ 
h_2 \\ 
h_3 \\ 
h_4 \\ 
\vdots \\ 
h_{n-3} \\
h_{n-2} \\ 
h_{n-1} \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 
0 \\ 
0 \\ 
0 \\ 
\vdots \\ 
0 \\
0 \\ 
-\frac{1^2}{1^2+(n-1)^2} \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

You only need one more step to solve a matrix equation to obtain $h_1$, $h_2$, ... ,$h_{n-1}$